# How can I convert a shape made out of pixels to vertices

Tags: vector-graphics, polygon, javascript, pixel-graphics

I'm trying to implement the solution to get the [minimum dissection into rectangles of a rectilinear polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919298/algorithm-for-finding-the-fewest-rectangles-to-cover-a-set-of-rectangles-without).

My shape is made out of pseudo-pixels (different width/height) but for the moment let's say it's only pixels.

I need to find a way to convert my shape to a vertices loop.

for example a simple pixel of coordinate `{50, 25}` would give me 4 vertices (to read clockwise) as follow `{{50, 25}{51, 25}{51, 26}{50, 26}}`.

Imagine now a more complex filled shape with holes in it like this one of 6 pixels height and 24 pixels width.

```
   S     
   |¯¯¯¯|    |¯¯¯¯¯¯|
 __|    |____|  __  |__
|              |__|    |
 ¯¯|    |¯¯¯¯|      |¯¯
   |____|    |______|
```

I can't seem to find the logic to parse my shape and convert it to vertices. Only thing I know is I think I will start parsing with pixel of coordinate `S` which is the top-left pixel of the shape.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: As a first start, the keyword you might be looking for is **contour finding/detection**. The point is finding connected curves along the black-white-discontuities in a binary image. There's a multitude of algorithms for that, but looking for that term might give you some first introductions to the problem.